# mails are going to spam folder when i change from mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

this mail going to spam. when i change email->from then it goes to inbox.
   how to send email to inbox with this email id
   $this->email>from("sweco@suzlon.com");

```
        $this->email->from("sweco@suzlon.com");
        $this->email->to("marmik0011@gmail.com");

        $this->email->subject($subject);       
        $this->email->message($body);
        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');

        $this->email->send();
```

this mail going to inbox.

```
        $this->email->from("info@gmail.com");
        $this->email->to("marmik0011@gmail.com");

        $this->email->subject($subject);       
        $this->email->message($body);
        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');

        $this->email->send();
```

Comment: gmail trying to find-out that `sweco@suzlon.com` is a valid gmail id or not? since it's not it goes to spam

Comment: Are you using a Gmail account to send emails?

Comment: The mail processing at suzlon.com is probably more picky than gmail. You should absolutely use SMTP to send email, as that will result in better email delivery to most domains. If possible, send your SMTP email through gmail, and you'd be almost completely assured that your emails will not be identified as spam (unless they have spammy content).

Comment: Try to use latest phpmailer, with full settings. Now a days spam filters  are very advance. In my experience codeigniter mails does not work properly when using custom emails. I use PHPmailer for this issue

Comment: create email with this email on your host `sweco@suzlon.com`

Answer (score 0):

3 things you need to do:

- `FROM` email should be existing (so create that one if not created)
- Add FROM Name too `Person Name <emailAddress>`
- Also, add an email address as `Reply-to` in headers